# Can I get a(n internationally-recognized) Debit card in the Netherlands?

Tags: netherlands, credit-cards

Some airline companies (easyJet in particular) don't seem to offer payment with [iDEAL](https://www.ideal.nl/en/), but do seem offer a reduced fee (quite significantly reduced - 9 EUR or so) for using a debit card, e.g. Mastercard Debit or Visa Debit.

Can I get one of those issued in the Netherlands?

Also, assuming the answer to the first question is affirmative: I have an ABN AMRO bank account and an ICS Mastercard (a credit card); do those help me / make it cheaper for me to get such a debit card?

Comment: How is this about expatriation? Even if you are an expatriate, how would the situation be different if you were not?

Comment: Would perhaps be more relevant on the money site?

Comment: Note that Maestro is internationally recognised alright, I used mine to withdraw cash all over the place, even outside the Eurozone and in quite exotic locales. You are really asking about something else, namely a card that supports online transactions. And the rules for that differ from merchant to merchant. Speaking about low-cost airlines, even a Visa Debit might not be enough to avoid extra fees, each have different rather arbitrary restrictions. As an example, if I am not mistaken, EasyJet waives the fee for a Visa Electron but not a Visa or Mastercard Debit.

Comment: As an owner of an ABN AMRO account and ICS Mastercard, I had a hard time finding a debit card. I ended up using the Mastercard (with transaction alerts enabled) whenever I can't pay with iDEAL or PayPal.

Comment: It is unclear for me, why do you want to have a debit card issued in Netherlands? Is it critical, if it will be issued in other EU country?

Comment: @AndreySapegin The OP wants something available in the Netherlands (because that's where he was a resident) that works with Easyjet's website without extra fees. Regular Dutch banks' offerings don't work for that because their debit cards do not allow online transactions except through the Dutch iDEAL system (which easyjet doesn't support).

Comment: (Online) bank based in other EU countries would obviously be acceptable as long as they offer services to Dutch residents (which wasn't the case for N26 when that question was written IIRC). Unfortunately, N26 isn't a good solution as they apparently issue a Mastercard debit card which isn't eligible for lower fees on easyjet.com either. Revolut switched from Visa Debit to Maestro for Dutch customers but I don't think those work either (that's the gist of my earlier comment on the question).

Comment: The real solution seems to have come from Easyjet though, if I am reading their website correctly, they lowered their fees for many cards (I haven't used them in two years), [*even credit cards and Amex!*](https://www.easyjet.com/en/terms-and-conditions/fees) They also added a SEPA direct debit option which should work with Dutch bank accounts, even without credit cards.

Comment: @Relaxed: Perhaps you could make that last comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are relatively new banking services that operate without physical branches, such as bunq and N26. You can see a comparison of those [here](https://www.finder.com/nl/en/bank-accounts/debit-cards). They use the international standard for debit cards. Therefore, they might solve your problem.

Comment: Are these an alternative to existing banks? Please clarify.

Comment: @einpoklum: what do you mean under "alternative to existing banks". Banks such as N26, Revolut, etc. do exist already and offer bank accounts including Visa/MasterCard at least for EU residents.

Comment: N26 is just a bank offering a regular Mastercard and wouldn't solve the OP's problem. In fact, it's not even that much cheaper than ABN-AMRO, except perhaps with foreign currency fees.

Comment: @bluesman80: I meant, are they banks you can be a client of as an alternative to ABN-AMRO and such, or just companies offering a card irrespective of your bank? ... and it seems the answe is the second. So it's not clear that answers my question. However, I do believe there are questions about bank choices for expats in the Netherlands.

Comment: @einpoklum Revolut wasn't a bank originally but seems to be moving in that direction. What bunq exactly is is unclear to me. N26 is a bank, marketed as such and with a license and desposit insurance. Depending on the services you expect, you could in principle use it as your main/only bank.

Comment: @Relaxed N26 offers Mastercard debit cards (and Maestro debit cards too for some countries based on residency, including Dutch residency) with a German IBAN (which companies [may not discriminate against](https://www.dnb.nl/en/payments/electronic-payments/sepa-and-iban-discrimination)). I don't see why that doesn't address the question, those cards can be used as debit cards (but not with iDeal).

Comment: @JJJ Last The heart of the question is Easyjet's payment conditions, the OP already had a perfectly workable debit card. A regular Mastercard debit card was not enough to avoid the fees (see my comments under the question). And if N26 has also started giving their Dutch customers a Maestro card instead (like Revolut started doing some time ago), that's not helpful at all, for Easyjet did not accept those. All this has become moot, though (see my answer).

Comment: @JJJ Like I said, the ABN-AMRO Maestro debit card that came with the OP's bank account (and, I assume all Maestro debit cards issued by Dutch banks) also fits that description. You can in fact use them abroad without any problem, I have done so many times. So even if you want to read the headline question a little too literally without trying to understand the actual problem, N26 doesn't seem to offer any advantage (where it differs a bit is online payments, not international recognition).

Comment: @JJJ That's true but my point is that either (a) you read the whole question and you know it is about payments for low-cost airlines and then you would understand why the N26 Mastercard wasn't a good solution or (b) you hide behind the headline question (“internationally recognized debit card“) and you have to conclude that any Maestro card will do for that question doesn't mention online payments at all. I don't disagree with your observations on the Dutch banking system but it just isn't relevant to the question at hand, no matter how you choose to read it.

Comment: @JJJ Yes, *now* you can do that with *any* Mastercard, credit, debit, ABN AMRO, N26, whatever. I already mentioned this so here again nothing surprising. You asked why the N26 Mastercard wasn't a good solution for the original question and I explained why, back when the question was asked it would attract the same fees as a credit card. It's a simple fact that I already mentioned several times. You do seem really bent on disagreeing, I don't know with what and why.

Comment: @Relaxed Yea reading back my later comments don't make a whole lot of sense. Apologies for getting into it so much and I'll delete my later comments as they don't really add much past your first response. Have nice weekend, :)

Answer (score 1):

I am yet to find a solution for your original problem (essentially getting a Visa Electron as a Dutch resident) but Easyjet seems to have changed their fee structure so that any [Dutch credit card](https://www.easyjet.com/en/terms-and-conditions/fees) should enable you to book a ticket with no additional fee. SEPA direct debit, when offered, should also work with a Dutch bank account.